# combine two pdo queries showing all results from the 2nd.

Tags: html, pdo

I had one table listing events and attendies. To try Database normalization i split this into two tables. 
I have made a database listing all the planned games for a team. 
Table 1

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+name   +  organiser  +  date  +  location  +  cost  +  notes  +  id+
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

i then have a second database that has everyone how has marked they will be comming
Table 2

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+id  +  event  +  player +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The id is unique to each, The id from table 1 is used as the event in table 2.

i have a simple PDO query that pulls the data from table 1 into a HTMl table

```
if($db->connect_error) {
                die("Connection error: ".$db->connect_error);
                }
                $sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY `date` ASC'
                ) or die($db->error);
                echo"";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))  
                {
                $a = $row['attendees'];//will look up attendies to tick a check box if already aknowledged
                $b = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                if (strpos($a,$b) !== false) {
                $c = "checked='checked'";
                    }else{
                $c = "";
                }   
                $r=$row['id'];
                echo "<div id='results'>";
                echo "<CENTER>";
                echo "<table  BORDER=6 class='fixed'>";
                echo "<TR> ";
                echo "<TD COLSPAN=3 ALIGN=CENTER><form action='going.php' method='post' name='form".$r."'>Event ".$row['name']." i'm going 
                <input type='checkbox' name='going'".$c." onclick='document.form".$r.".submit ();'>
                <input type='text' name='Organise' value='".$r."'>
                <input type='text' name='name' value='".$b."'>
                </form></TD>";
                echo "</TR> ";
                echo "<TR>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo "<B><u><font color='#0080FF'>Title </font></b></u>".$row['name']."<br></font>";
                echo "<B><u><font color='#0080FF'>Orginiser </font></b></u>".$row['organiser']."<br></font>";
                echo "<B><u><font color='#0080FF'>When </font></b></u>".date("D j-M-Y GA",$row['dt'])."<br></font>";
                echo "<B><u><font color='#0080FF'>Location </font></b></u>".$row['location']."<br></font>";
                echo "<B><u><font color='#0080FF'>Cost </font></b></u>£".$row['cost']."<br></font></TD>";
                echo "<TD ROWSPAN=3 valign='top'><B><u><font color='#0080FF'>Attendies </font></b></u>".$row['attendees']."<br></font></TD>";//will change to table 2                   
                echo "<TD ROWSPAN=3 valign='top'><B><u><font color='#0080FF'>notes </font></b></u>".$row['notes']."<br></font></TD>";       
                echo "</tr>";                   
                echo "</table>";
                echo "</CENTER>";
                echo "</div>";
                }
```

i have tried and joind these using

```
                    $sql = $db->query('SELECT t1.*, t2.event as t2event, t2.player as player
                FROM `event` as t1
                LEFT JOIN `going` as t2 on t1.id = t2.event
                ORDER BY t1.`dt` ASC'
```

but all i got was a HTML table per event and per player. I'm sure its possible but can't work it out, can i create a html table from quering table 1 and add to attendies all those going from table 2 not just one or creating a result each one. ?

Comment: Your question is not really clear, Can you show an example somewhere of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Miguel, i have placed it on a server at [link](https://david.russellweb.eu/live/test.php). It show three events comming up i wish to add people from the second table to the attendies section. E,G, select * from table 2 where event = (event number from table 1) and display the result in the html table attendies section.